# How to properly use style format in apache-poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to format my excel generated file from my java code. This is what my code snippet looks like:

```
...
Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
CellStyle textCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
if (rowNum % 2 == 0) {
    textCellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
    textCellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    textCellStyle.setFont(textFonts1);
} else {
    textCellStyle.setFont(textFonts2);
}

cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(student != null ? student.getIdNumber() : "");
cell.setCellStyle(textCellStyle);
...
```

My expectation was all **even rows** will be filled with **green background** but the produced output was different, instead it produced **black background**. I already tried different color or even changing my fill pattern but i always get black.

I am using **poi-3.17 and poi-ooxml-3.17, excel 2007** and java 1.6

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set a fill pattern for the cell as **FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND**. But you did not set a foreground color. This means that the standard color (black) is used as the foreground color.

Try to exchange...

```
textCellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
```

... with ...

```
textCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
```

... and it should render as you expect. The text in the cells should also be visible.

It seems counterintuitive to set a foreground color and fill pattern when you want to set a background though.

Comment: Thank your for response sir. I tried your suggestion but still it yields a black background color.

Comment: I have edited my answer with another aspect. Can you please try?

Answer (score 1):

I'm an Apache POI newbie and don't know much about the details yet. But—in some circumstances—what follows may be useful to you.

This code...

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class CellBackground {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
    int rowNum = 0;
    for (FillPatternType fpt : FillPatternType.values()) {
      Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
      Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
      XSSFCellStyle textCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
      textCellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
      textCellStyle.setFillPattern(fpt);
      cell.setCellValue(fpt.name());
      cell.setCellStyle(textCellStyle);
      sheet.createRow(rowNum++).setHeightInPoints(7);
    }
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);

    OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("CellBackground.xlsx");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    wb.close();
  }
}
```

...will produce this output in LibreOffice Calc (Apache POI 4.0.1):

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this is because i am using old technology. I tried your code but i still get Black Back ground. :(

Comment: When using Apache POI 3.17 (and likely other Apache POI versions prior to that as well) the font color is per default black. So to get the same results as in the screenshot above the font color has to be set manually.